# Problem when sending a webrequest

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

I use the following method to retrieve something from a webservice using a HTTPWebRequest:

```
private void RetrieveSourceCode(Method method)
{
   try
      {
      String url = "http://123.123.123.123:8080/";

      CredentialCache myCache = new CredentialCache();
      myCache.Add(new Uri(url), "Basic", new NetworkCredential("user", "pwd"));

     HttpWebRequest request =(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://abc.abc.ch:8080/famixParser/projects/argouml/org.argouml.uml.ui.behavior.common_behavior.ActionAddSendActionSignal.doIt(java.util.Collection)");
     Console.WriteLine(request.RequestUri.ToString());
     request.Credentials = myCache;
     request.Accept = "text/plain";

     HttpWebResponse response;
     try
     {
         response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("exception when sending query: ");
        throw e;
     }
     Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
     byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     string tempString = null;
     int count = 0;

     do
     {
                    // fill the buffer with data
                    count = resStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);

                    // make sure we read some data
                    if (count != 0)
                    {
                        // translate from bytes to ASCII text
                        tempString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, count);

                        // continue building the string
                        sb.Append(tempString);
                    }
                }
                while (count > 0); // any more data to read?

                String sourceCode = sb.ToString();
                method.setSourceCode(sourceCode);
                Console.WriteLine(sourceCode);
                request.Abort();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }


        }
```

Now I always get a 401 - Access denied exception. I don't know why, because if i use the same URL in my webbrowser, it works. Is it maybe because of the parantheses?

Please note: I changed the server address here, so its not working here, but I had to do it for confidentiality reasons.

Comment: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ is a great tool for helping debug stuff like this.

Comment: Obviously it looks like your credentials are not going across to the server. When you say using a browser works, how are you doing the authentication when using a browser? What kind of authentication does the service require. As @Merlyn suggested, you fiddler to see what the raw http traffic is when using your browser versus your code.

Comment: @Shiv Kumar. Yes as I mentioned in the comment of the answer below that was the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cache url and request url are different, I would think that means your username and password aren't being passed in the request.

```
String url = "http://123.123.123.123:8080/";

CredentialCache myCache = new CredentialCache();
myCache.Add(new Uri(url), "Basic", new NetworkCredential("user", "pwd"));
```

uses 123.123

```
HttpWebRequest request =(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://abc.abc.ch:8080/famixParser/projects/argouml/org.argouml.uml.ui.behavior.common_behavior.ActionAddSendActionSignal.doIt(java.util.Collection)");
```

uses abc.ch

Comment: You're really a genius! This urls are just examples and I modified it here for this question only and I didn't checked if both are the same. But nevertheless I noticed that in my real code the urls are also different! Problem solved!